# how can source() print the last command executed [r]

Tags: r, debugging

I am inside the R workspace and I use the command `source('myscript.r')` to launch a script. But this script crashes somewhere and then R prompts the quit workspace question. Because this is useful for me for debugging purposes I would like to know what is the last command executed which also should be the command that crashes the execution. I have played with the source() arguments but I am not able to display the last command parsed.

Is there also a way to prevent R from quitting after an error?

EDIT: I think the problem is into a function called by myscript.r, so source() doesn't print any command executed in that function.

EDIT2: Here is an example

```
qair2rh = function(qair, temp, pres){
temp=temp-273.15
pres=pres*0.01
e <- qair * pres / (0.378 * qair + 0.622)
es <- 6.112 * exp((17.67 * temp)/(temp + 243.5))
rh <- e / es
return(rh)
}

qair=10
temp=20
pres=2
rh=qair2rh(qair, temp, pres)
```

source doesn't print any of the commands executed inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Set `echo = TRUE` or `verbose = TRUE`.

Comment: it doesn't work, most of the output is omitted or truncated.

Comment: @user4050 What doesn't work? How does it not work? Please show an [MRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user4050 That is insufficient information. In addition to telling us what you think, show us what is going on.